# Set contentDescription for a custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, accessibility

how can I set a `contentDescription` to be read by the accessibility service when my dialog is opened? I'm currently using a dialog with a custom layout to display a blocking laoding screen and the spoken `contentDescription` is "Alert", which is not appropriate in this circumstance.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create subclass `Dialog` and override `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent` to provide your own accessibility text.

Here's an example:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        event.getText().add("Your message goes here");
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
}
```